# What does " backtick escapes " mean in chinese?

Tags: word

***I learn Mathematica on the site StackExchange Mathematica,I encountered a problem?***(on the picture)[image: problem]

*backtick escapes*

The result that the dictionary gives is "那些逃离",Obviously,it is wrong.
So my question is how to understand it in Chinese or English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "backtick", also known as a "backquote", is a punctuation mark that appears to be translated as 反引号 and refers to this symbol:

`` ` ``

In the programming context, "escape" often refers to an "escape sequence", which is translated as [转义序列](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BD%AC%E4%B9%89%E5%BA%8F%E5%88%97). I'm guessing that "backtick escapes" is used to mean 反引号转义字符.

[edited per user58955's comment]

Comment: the 代表 shouldn't be there... 反引号转义字符 would sound simply fine

Comment: @user58955 corrected... thanks!

Comment: @user58955,@Claw,Thanks for your help sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

This is a backtick: `

It's sort of like a single-quote (') or a double-quote ("), but not the same. When you put `backticks around stuff` then it will `appear like this`.